# How to do Multilevel menu the correct way with MySQL PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a menu that is a main menu that goes 2 levels deep(sub menu and sub sub menu).

I have done this before with GROUP_CONCAT, but that was only 1 level deep.  The fact that this is 2 levels deep is really throwing me for a loop for the best practices.

```
CREATE TABLE `database`.`main_menu` ( `main_menu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `main_menu_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`main_menu_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `database`.`sub_menu` ( `main_menu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , `sub_menu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `sub_menu_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`sub_menu_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `database`.`sub_sub_menu` ( `main_menu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , `sub_menu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL , `sub_sub_menu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `sub_sub_menu_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`sub_sub_menu_id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `main_menu` (`main_menu_id`, `main_menu_name`) VALUES (NULL, 'Food'), (NULL, 'Treats')

INSERT INTO `sub_menu` (`main_menu_id`, `sub_menu_id`, `sub_menu_name`) VALUES ('1', NULL, 'Duck'), ('1', NULL, 'Chicken')
INSERT INTO `sub_menu` (`main_menu_id`, `sub_menu_id`, `sub_menu_name`) VALUES ('2', NULL, 'Bacon Bits'), ('2', NULL, 'Dental')

INSERT INTO `sub_sub_menu` (`main_menu_id`, `sub_menu_id`, `sub_sub_menu_id`, `sub_sub_menu_name`) VALUES ('1', '1', NULL, 'In Gravy'), ('1', '2', NULL, 'in Soup')

INSERT INTO `sub_sub_menu` (`main_menu_id`, `sub_menu_id`, `sub_sub_menu_id`, `sub_sub_menu_name`) VALUES ('2', '3', NULL, 'Sticks'), ('2', '4', NULL, 'Chunks')
```

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT ssm.sub_sub_menu_name  as    sub_sub_menu_name ,
sm.sub_menu_name  as    sub_menu_name ,
mm.main_menu_name  as   main_menu_name ,

ssm.sub_sub_menu_id  as     sub_sub_menu_id ,
sm.sub_menu_id  as      sub_menu_id ,
mm.main_menu_id  as     main_menu_id 

FROM        main_sub_sub_menu  as ssm
LEFT JOIN main_menu as mm
    ON mm.main_menu_id  = ssm.main_menu_id 
LEFT JOIN sub_menu as sm
    ON sm.sub_menu_id   = ssm.sub_menu_id  

ORDER BY ssm.sub_sub_menu_id, sm.sub_menu_id, ssm.main_menu_id
```

PHP here on how to divide the information into categories:

```
<?php $cat = $getData->get_menu_categories(); //SQL Query above with PDO
$i = 1;
$j = 1;
for($a=0; $a<= count($cat); $a++){
        if($i == $cat[$a]['main_menu_id']){
            for($j=1; $j < count($cat[$a]['sub_menu_id']); $j++){ // Was getting stuck here because I can't count it unless it is an array
                 //Would show each submenu name, then I would make another for loop for the sub sub menu 
            }
        }else{
            $i++;
        }
```

Output would be

Main menu

Sub Menu

Sub Sub Menu

I am making Lists( a `<ul><li>` style html menu list ), basically a tree.

Comment: Your question is not so clear to me.  Can you rephrase it by showing sample table data along with the expected output?

Comment: Hopefully that helps.  Just a <ul><li> style list with a parent, child, then child of a child menu

Comment: I was wondering if my logic of the MySQL query is wrong in how I am getting the data before I am trying to do the PHP?

Comment: I don't see what you are trying to do, so I can't really comment.

Comment: http://www.php-guru.in/2013/dynamic-menu-in-php-mysql-javascript/  Hopefully this helps in explaining what I am trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to loop through the results of the query and print something like this. I've used dashes to indent, but you can use html to do that more cleanly. I've made a db fiddle for anyone else who wants to help. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sbTyQbNemcEM5vX3xwuUaJ/0#&togetherjs=wkJd3lwafs

```
<?php 
$cat = $getData->get_menu_categories(); 
$lastmain = '';
$lastsub = '';
$lastsubsub = '';

foreach ($cat as $line) {
   $main = $line['main_menu_name'];
   $sub = $line['sub_menu_name'];
   $subsub = $line['sub_sub_menu_name'];

   if ($lastmain <> $main) {
       print "$main\n";
       $lastmain = $main;
   }

   if ($lastsub <> $sub) {
       print "---$sub\n";
       $lastsub = $sub;
   }

   if ($lastsubsub <> $subsub) {
       print "------$subsub\n";
       $lastsubsub = $subsub;
   }
}
```

Comment: That was the most simple, and direct code that works great.  I have spent a couple days trying to figure this out. :)  Now I just have to add IDs

Comment: It also helped me to change the SQL ORDER BY ssm.main_menu_id ASC,  msm.sub_menu_id ASC, ssm.main_sub_sub_menu_id ASC

Answer (score 2):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     id              |  menu_name       |   parent_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      1              |Main Menu         |     null         |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      2              |sub Menu          |      1           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      3              |sub sub Menu      |      2           |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Design your table like this, so you dont have to make table for each sub element and you can go upto any level inside.

Comment: So it doesn't have to be in separate tables.  Good to know. :)

Comment: For most use cases, this is a better way to represent hierarchical data, as you can have an infinte level of menus. HOWEVER, menus tend to have a limited breadth and limited depth, and the data structure you have is more than adequate. Another option is to store the menu in the form of XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul class="nav__list">

<?php
// $cat = $getData->get_menu_categories(); // put your SQL request to the database here
$lastmain = '';
$lastsub = '';
$lastsubsub = '';
$mainx=1;
$mainy=0;
$subx=0;
$suby=0;
$subsubx=0;
$subsuby=0;
$startmainx = 0;
?>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav__list">
<?php
foreach ($cat as $line) {
   $main = $line['main_menu_name'];
   $sub = $line['sub_menu_name'];
   $subsub = $line['sub_sub_menu_name'];

   $mainid = $line['main_menu_id'];
   $subid = $line['sub_menu_id'];
   $subsubid = $line['sub_sub_menu_id'];

   if ($lastmain <> $main) {
        if($mainx <> $mainy){
            if($startmainx == 0){
                $mainx = $mainy;
                $startmainx =1;
            }else{
                print '</ul></li></ul></li>';//beginning
                $mainx = $mainy;
            }
        }
       echo '<li>
       <input id="group-'.$subid.'" type="checkbox" hidden />
       <label for="group-'.$subid.'">'.$main.'&nbsp; <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></label>';
        if(($mainx == $mainy) && ($lastmain == '')){
            echo '<ul class="group-list">';
            $mainx++;
        }
       $lastmain = $main;
        if(($mainx == $mainy) && ($lastmain == $main)){
            echo '<ul class="group-list"><li>'; //end
            $lastsub = '';
            $mainx++;
        }
   }//end 1st menu 
   if ($lastsub <> $sub) {
    if(($subx <> $suby) && ($lastsub == '')){
        $suby++;
    }
    if($subx <> $suby){
        print "</ul>";
        $suby++;
    }
       echo '<input id="sub-group-'.$subsubid.'" type="checkbox" hidden />
       <label for="sub-group-'.$subsubid.'">'.$sub.'&nbsp; <span class="fa fa-angle-right"></span></label>';
        $lastsub = $sub;
        if($subx == $suby){
                echo '<ul class="sub-group-list">';
            $subx++;
        }
   }//End 2nd menu
   if ($lastsubsub <> $subsub) {
        if($subsubx <> $subsuby){
            $subsubx =$subsuby;
        }
       echo '<li><a href="'.$subsubid.'">'.$subsub.'</a></li>';
        $lastsubsub = $subsub;
        if($subsubx == $subsuby){
           $subsubx = $subsuby;
        }
   }
}
?>
```

I wanted to show everyone how I added html into this based on mankowitz's answer.